# Python find URLs in HTML without parsing

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I have a chunk of HTML text, and I need to programmatically search this text for URLs, however, parsing the document isn't going to work.

For example, parsing the document using something like Beautiful Soup:

```
    #Find Links
    for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
        self.parseResult(link)
```

Would only capture a url in the form:

```
<a href="#">Something</a>
```

But, what if I want to go beyond this, and capture URLs referenced **anywhere** in the document? Such as:

```
<!-- See this URL for more information on the HTML code below: http://example.com -->
```

Or:

```
Go to the /FAQ page for more information
```

Does anyone know how I might go about this? I was thinking about using a combination of BeautifulSoup and Regex, however, I can't think of how RegEx would be able to scrape any relative URLs.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why not just search for URLs in the HTML document itself?

Comment: Can you suggest a method for this?

Comment: Instead of building a Beautiful Soup object out of the HTML response body, just search the raw response text itself.